# How to store an RFID tag number in a string

Tags: ethernet, cpp

I want to send RFID tag number to PHP page. So far I have sent a fixed string to php and it worked, now I am not getting data in string when i scan rfid tag. I want to store every RFID tag number in a string when it is scanned, so that I can send it to php page.

```
if (rfid.isCard()) {

    String rfid_uid = "";
    if (rfid.readCardSerial()) {
        String rfid_uid = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            Serial.print(rfid.serNum[i], HEX);
            rfid_uid = rfid.serNum[i];
        }

        Serial.println();
    }
    //delay(7000);
    Serial.print("User ID \n");
    Serial.println(rfid_uid);
    make_request(rfid_uid);
}
```

This is the path to php page

```
         String method = "GET /ethernet/data.php?rfid_uid=";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String rfid_uid = "";
if (rfid.readCardSerial()) {
    String rfid_uid = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        Serial.print(rfid.serNum[i], HEX);
        rfid_uid = rfid.serNum[i];
    }

    Serial.println();
}
```

This code has multiple problems:

- the variable `rfid_uid` is defined twice, they are overshadowing each other. The inner part only assigns a value to the `rfid_uid` delcared in the inside of the `if` statement, the outer `rfid_uid` will remain empty
- As you can see with `Serial.print(rfid.serNum[i], HEX);`, the element `rfid.serNum[i]` is an integer, which is printed as hex. (e.g. 123 = `7B`), in `rfid_uid = rfid.serNum[i];` you however assign the direct numerical value, without converting it to hex

You can try the following, if you want the serial number as a 4 byte hex string:

```
String rfid_uid = "";
if (rfid.readCardSerial()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        String uid_part = String(rfid.serNum[i], HEX); 
        Serial.print(uid_part);
        rfid_uid += uid_part;
    }

    Serial.println();
}
//rest as before
```

This should construct a `String` object from the integer in `HEX` format and append (using the `+=` operator it to the `rfid_uid` string). Thus, after 4 iterations, the `String` value is built up and can be used in the request.

Comment: https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/04/the-evils-of-arduino-strings/

Answer (score 0):

[do not use String](https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/04/the-evils-of-arduino-strings/)

```
char url[64];
sprintf(url, "GET /ethernet/data.php?rfid_uid=%02x%02x%02x%02x", rfid[0], rfid[1], rfid[2], rfid[3]);
```